# Can't create file from Uri after recent android update

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

Recent update now prevents creation of file from uri.

I created an app that gets a file from an `Intent`. Where the `Intent` action is equal to `"ACTION_SEND"`. I get the `Uri` using

```
(Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
```

And then get the file using

```
final File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
```

However after a recent update to android, this is not creating a file as `file.exists()` is false

`fileUri.getPath()` is /share_pdf/New Doc 2019-05-03 12.50.49.pdf

Manifest has these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am expecting to get a file, however I no longer do. Is there now a new way to get a file from a Uri?